# Link to PDF opens html page with garbled text on iPad in all browsers

Tags: html, ios, ipad, pdf, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle APEX application where users can download their monthly invoices as PDFs, but in all browsers on iPad when the user clicks on the download link the browser attempts to open the PDF as an HTML file that looks something like this:

> %PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ 1 0 obj <>stream ÿØÿàJFIF``ÿÛC
>    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ»9"ÿÄ
>   ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚
>   %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ
>   ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ $4á%ñ ...

The links that are generated by APEX are formatted like http://example.com/f?p=APP_ID:PAGE_ID:SESSION:DOWNLOAD:NO:PAGE_ID:PID_INVOICE_ID:4435755&cs=3F3EGeKIp-0SMhnM98SL3ikLam32 so there is no file extension in the URL, which I believe is the problem. The browser is likely assuming the MIME-TYPE from the URL rather than the header. Right clicking on the link doesn't give the option to save the target rather than open it, so iPad users have absolutely no way of retrieving their invoices.

I have tried adding the HTML5 "download" attribute to the links, like  `<a href="http://example.com" download>Download</a>`, setting `type="application/pdf"` and also reinstalling Adobe Reader. I have been researching the issue for three days with no luck so hopefully somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the shared components -> Report Queries
in there you can choose the output file format as pdf, doc, xml etc.
and output method as inline or attachement

as i see from the link you gave option for DOWNLOAD is NO

Comment: This wasn't the solution, but you definitely steered my brain down the right direction. It's actually not an APEX issue at all. There's a custom script that a coworker wrote that is serving the PDF files, so I'll need to pass the issue on to him. Thank you very much for your comment, though.